# openssl インストール時にgcc のエラー

Tags: amazon-ec2, gcc, makefile

Amazon Linux AMIに openssl-1.0.2j をソースインストールをしようとしておりますが、gccがインストールされているにも関わらず make 時にgcc: コマンドが見つかりませんでしたというエラーが出てきてしまいます。gcc はversion 4.8.3 がyumでインストールしております。

```
[root@ip openssl-1.0.2j]# make
making all in crypto...
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2j/crypto' に入ります
/usr/bin/perl ../util/mkbuildinf.pl "gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM" "linux-x86_64" >buildinf.h
gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM   -c -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
make[1]: gcc: コマンドが見つかりませんでした
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] エラー 127
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/usr/src/openssl-1.0.2j/crypto' から出ます
make: *** [build_crypto] エラー 1
```

Comment: `$ which gcc`を実行するとどんな結果が出ますか？

Comment: @todashuta /usr/bin/gcc になります！

Comment: rootで実行したときでも同じように`/usr/bin/gcc`になりますか？

Comment: @todashuta ↑はrootでの実行結果になります。

Comment: この質問を読んだ人が再現できるように実施した手順を可能な限り省略せず書けますか？